# $n ^{\rm th}$ digit of an irrational number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, irrational-numbers

Is there a way to directly find the $n ^{\rm th}$ digit of the fractional part of an irrational number?

For example, how can I find the $1000^{\rm th}$ digit of $\{\pi\}$?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula).

Comment: As far as I know, such a method was only discovered for $\pi$ and only in base $2$. Usually, you will have to calculate the number precisely enough.

Comment: @Infiaria I Knew Plouffe formula. But it only works for pi.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE There's more formulae on that page for other irrational constants.

Comment: I talked too faster

Comment: You can't have a formula for each irrational. The set of formulas is countable, the set of irrationals is not. There are irrationals which can't be computed, like [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).

Comment: And Plouffe's formula is not actually direct, it requires some of the first digits of the number. It is more efficient than brute force, but does not give the result "immediately".

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411418

Answer (score 1):

The family of algorithms called [spigot algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm) are designed to do just that: generate digits within the the $b$-ary expansion of irrational constants (for some integer $b>2$).

For your example of $\pi$, the [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) gives rise to such a spigot algorithm specifically for $\pi$.